# Screen Snip/Capture Utility callable from API or command line?

Tags: windows, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Take a screen shot from command line in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/75614/take-a-screen-shot-from-command-line-in-windows)

I am looking for a screen capture tool that is controllable from the command line. Ideally I would pass the filename, and possibly some options (capture mouse pointer or not, etc..), then it would take control, allow the user to select a region of the screen, and then save it to the specified file and disappear.

```
screensnip.exe /output c:\users\public\pictures\screenshot.png /hidecursor
```

- User draws rectangle on screen
- Control passes back to batch file, script, etc...