# Is there a way to capture the window of the input method window?

Tags: windows, screen-capture, ime, snipping-tool

The window of an input method application is hard to capture. It will disappear if you try to press shortcut key to capture the current screen. Even if you press `Print Screen` key, it will disappear too, making it tricky to capture the window.

Right now, I have to record my window to *capture* the IME window (see GIF below), which I am not very satisfied.

[image: kymgxS.gif]

Is there a direct way to capture this window?

Comment: You could try timing the screencapture via a script. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/76362/885475) suggests how, using the freeware [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and the `cmdwait` command. 

You can run the script, then open the window while it's waiting. That way there is no buttonpress to interrupt it.

Comment: Thanks, I have found snipaste works well to capture the IME window. See my answer below.

Comment: Which OS and which IME is this? I don't have these problems on Win7 and Win10, but the IME looks different.

Answer (score 4):

After posting this question in several places, I got the answer I want. I will summarize below.

1. Use [Snipaste](https://www.snipaste.com/) (I am using fast stone capture right now).
2. Use the Windows 10 shortcut `Win + Shift +S`( after Fall Creator update, Windows 10 Ver 1703), see references [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/capturing-screen-contents-the-prntscrn-key-win/df0f73fb-286f-4588-aace-357fe3b5422a). It will put the captured screen on clipboard. You can then paste the captured image to other tools to save it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use snipping tool [delayed](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/windows-10-snipping-tool-delay-capture-pop-up-menus/) feature in windows 10.

[image]

Or follow [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots) process:

- open snipping tool
- create the screen you want to capture
- press ctrl + printscrn
- press new in snipping tool and create capture