# How can a running application be set as the active window via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, screen-capture

To take screenshot of the desktop by [this snippet](https://superuser.com/a/1411215/1014819), I want to be sure my application is in the captured image.

When that code runs per minute, how can I be sure my application would be in front of others? As the code is a PowerShell snippet, I was thinking of mixing it with something to temporarily activate my application when it goes to take the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Where is your code?

What errors are you having?

Native PowerShell is not designed to be a GUI management tool.
You can do it, but there is no built-in cmdlet to do so.

You have to lean on either [SendKeys](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/provide-input-to-applications-with-powershell), .NET, or third-party [add-on](https://eddytechdotnet.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/using-wasp-and-powershell-for-powerful-windows-gui-automation/) [or](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell) [tools](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

A simple [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad) example with SendKeys: (as long as your application is not minimized)...
So, start Notepad, click another application to ring it to foreground, then run the code below, which should brig Notepad to the foreground.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic") 
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate((Get-Process -Name notepad).MainWindowTitle)
```

… if it is minimized, then that will not work. More code is needed to restore minimized windows. I'll leave that as a homework assignment for you.

Comment: Thanks | What I tried is searching! I'm new in powershell scripting. I read some manuals and searched. So I couldn't implement it, then no error! | Mine is a simple loop calling that snippet as a function, described here: https://superuser.com/q/1419761/1014819 | Homework?! :'(

Comment: See the update I posted relative to the link you supplied here.

Comment: The IT department might prohibit SendKeys from being installed. Couldn't the same be achieved in PowerShell (importing the same DLL files)?